# jQGrid with jquery tooltip tools

Tags: php, jquery, sql, jqgrid, tooltip

I am using this [tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) that is jQuery based on a web page that has a jQGrid element in it.
The tooltip works fine for all the non jQgrid elements from the page. 
I am trying to apply the tooltip to the columns of the grid to show specific data returned from the ajax call with no succes.
The tooltip is set to use the "title" keyword.
Here is a what i am using to make the grid:

```
var myGrid = jQuery("#clients_lingots");
myGrid.jqGrid({
url:'lingots.php',
datatype: 'xml',
height:700,
mtype: 'GET',
deepempty:true ,
colNames:['Nom client'],
colModel :[ 
  {name:'Name', index:'Name', width:1600,align:'left'},
          ],

rowNum:3000,
pager: '#pager_clients_lingots',
sortname: 'Name',
sortorder: 'asc',
viewrecords: true,
caption: 'Clients lingots',
....etc
```

In my lingots.php file that returns the data from the server (some sql querys) i've put a cell like

```
$s .= "<cell>&lt;a title='Date creation:".$datecreation."Derniere modification:'>".$qualite."&lt;/a></cell>";
```

to return a cell like `<a title='some info for the tooltip from db">data.for.the.cell</a>` thinking that the tooltip will work.

i think that the tooltip has a problem detecting the ajax call data.
I do not know how to fix this.
Any ideas?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

please try with syntax.
 title='some info for the tooltip from db'
or
 title="some info for the tooltip from db"

if you started with '' or ""; check it.

Answer (score 0):

OK,i've found the answer myself using the gridComplete function like the following example and disabling the "title" atribute in colModel properties like "title:false":

```
gridComplete: function(){$("[title]").tooltip({position: "bottom right",effect: 'slide'});}
```